# What is the best way to create a 10x10 grid and print it in the console?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *theBoard = [NSMutableArray array];

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
{
    [theBoard addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"o"]];
} 

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
    NSLog(@"       %@",[[theBoard subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0+(i*10), 10)]componentsJoinedByString:@"  "]);
}
```

Console output:

```
o o o o o o o o o o
o o o o o o o o o o
o o o o o o o o o o
o o o o o o o o o o
o o o o o o o o o o
o o o o o o o o o o
o o o o o o o o o o
o o o o o o o o o o
o o o o o o o o o o
o o o o o o o o o o
```

I need to work with the **coordinates of the array**. How can I solve this problem?

What is the best way to create a 10x10 grid and print it in the console?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow first of all! Secondly, this site is mainly designed to help you overcome programming problems when you hit a rough spot and can't get past it. To get high quality answers, be sure to post what you've tried, what result you're currently getting, and what the desired result is. You need to show what you've attempted in order to get the highest quality answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use a two dimensional array.**

Here is how to do it:

```
NSArray *rowArray = @[@"o", @"o", @"o", @"o", @"o", @"o", @"o", @"o", @"o", @"o",];
NSMutableArray *board = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];

for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < 10; rowIndex ++)
{
    [board addObject:[rowArray mutableCopy]];
}
```

Let's **print the board** to the console:

```
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < 10; rowIndex ++)
{
    NSArray *row = board[rowIndex];

    NSLog(@"|%@|", [row componentsJoinedByString:@" "]);
}
```

Now you can reference each field on the board with **X,Y coordinates**:

```
board[yourXLocation][yourYLocation];
```

Side note. You can also declare your array in more visual way. To see what is going on.

Example of an 3x3 array:

```
NSArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:@[@[ @"o", @"o", @"o"],
                                                           @[ @"o", @"o", @"o"],
                                                           @[ @"o", @"o", @"o"]]];
```

Comment: Thank you. But now how I can print this array in console (to see grid 10*10)?

Comment: I updated my answer with code that prints the board to the console.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a multi-dimensional array, or in this case a 2d array. This will allow you to find elements using something like `theBoard[0][0]`

```
NSMutableArray *theBoard = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    NSMutableArray *row = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
         [row addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"o"]];
    }
    [theBoard addObject:row];
}
```